# Open outlook with To field from Excel vba

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I want to open outlook compose email window with only To field filled.

In c#, if we write "mailto:abc@abc.com", then it will open up compose email window with To field.

Is it possible using Excel vba?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried below code, and it worked like a charm.

```
Sub CreateStatusReportToBoss()
  Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem

  Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
  Set outApp = New Outlook.Application

  Set myItem = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("mail@abc.com")

  myItem.Subject = "Status Report"
  myItem.Display
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The VBA `Hyperlinks.Add` method is what you want (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx).

```
...
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(4,4).Value = "someone@somewhere.com"
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(4, 4), _
    Address:="mailto:someone@somewhere.com"
End With
```

Comment: What if i want to do that on button click?

Comment: Then add the suggested code (or similar) to a button handler. The link [https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283)  offers a reasonable explanation for adding a button and associated event handling code.

Comment: Above code open up the website, instead it should open outlook compose email window.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Could it be the default mail application hasn't been defined on your deployment system? On Windows 7 (via registry) and Win 8 (via settings UI) you can associate specific protocols with particular applications. Could it be the 'MAILTO' protocol is currently associated with your browser instead of mail client?

Comment: Thanks @VirtualMichael for your help, i have search on this and found the working code. Please check my answer.

Comment: Ok. That assumes your mail client is always Outlook though. Doing it the Hyperlink way (with the `mailto:` protocol as per your question) should be mail client independent.